# RunDLL Error... Module could not be found

Tags: windows-7, virus

I keep getting this error on my computer and I can't find any way to get rid of it.  I've looked all over the internet. Can anyone help?

**Operating System:** Windows 7
**When it occurs:** Randomly, 3 of them just pop-up.

[image]

Comment: "If you are seeing an RunDLL pop-up error from SysMenu.dll (C:\PROGRA~1\COMMON~1\System\SysMenu.dll) when starting Windows, then your computer is infected with an adware program." See [Remove SysMenu.dll RunDLL error from Windows Start-up](https://malwaretips.com/blogs/remove-sysmenu-dll-virus/)

Answer (score 1):

I am posting this as an answer to the question, even though @DavidPostill answered it in the comments section.

You have a virus.  [Here's the documentation](https://malwaretips.com/blogs/remove-sysmenu-dll-virus/) on how to remove it.